# python json.loads <type 'exceptions.ValueError'> (Expecting property name: line 1 column 3 (char 2))

Tags: python, json

I'm working on a python CGI script that will accept a JSON string as input then process it. While testing it I keep throwing ValueErrors, and I'm not sure why.

Here's a snippet that illustrates the issue:

```
import json, pprint
a = """[{u'airline': u'JYX',
  u'arrivaltime': u'2018-02-23 12:33:00.0',
  u'departuretime': u'2018-02-23 09:21:00.0',
  u'flightno': u'XX1021',
  u'fltdate': u'2018-02-23',
  u'fltdest': u'ZYHB',
  u'fltdest_iata': None,
  u'fltid': u'1035783',
  u'fltori': u'ZSWZ',
  u'fltori_iata': None,
  u'in_timestamp': u'2018-02-23 12:40:00.0',
  u'msid': u'INRP',
  u'out_timestamp': u'2018-02-23 09:09:00.0',
  u'tail': u'B-XXXX'},
 {u'airline': u'JYX',
  u'arrivaltime': u'2018-02-23 23:57:00.0',
  u'departuretime': u'2018-02-23 20:42:00.0',
  u'flightno': u'XX1022',
  u'fltdate': u'2018-02-23',
  u'fltdest': u'ZSWZ',
  u'fltdest_iata': None,
  u'fltid': u'1036068',
  u'fltori': u'ZYHB',
  u'fltori_iata': None,
  u'in_timestamp': None,
  u'msid': u'ONRP',
  u'out_timestamp': u'2018-02-23 20:37:00.0',
  u'tail': u'B-YYYY'}]"""

b = json.loads(a)
print "A:"
pprint.pprint(a)
print "B:"
pprint.pprint(b)
```

When I run it I get ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 3 (char 2)

Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dummy.py", line 31, in <module>
    b = json.loads(a)
  File "/Users/danmahoney/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/danmahoney/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/danmahoney/anaconda/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

I have passed the JSON through an online validator, so I'm kind of at a loss as to what's causing JSON to puke on this data. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't JSON at all. It looks like the string representation of a Python data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are not valid in JSON. You need to use double quotes for strings and keys.

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid JSON.

the `u'string'` and `None` are python string representations and not JSON representations.

try this on for size:

```
import json, pprint                                                                                                                                                                                        
a = """                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 {"airline": "JYX",                                                                                                                                                                                        
  "arrivaltime": "2018-02-23 12:33:00.0",                                                                                                                                                                  
  "departuretime": "2018-02-23 09:21:00.0",                                                                                                                                                                
  "flightno": "XX1021",                                                                                                                                                                                    
  "fltdate": "2018-02-23",                                                                                                                                                                                 
  "fltdest": "ZYHB",                                                                                                                                                                                       
  "fltdest_iata": "",                                                                                                                                                                                      
  "fltid": "1035783",                                                                                                                                                                                      
  "fltori": "ZSWZ",                                                                                                                                                                                        
  "fltori_iata": "",                                                                                                                                                                                       
  "in_timestamp": "2018-02-23 12:40:00.0",                                                                                                                                                                 
  "msid": "INRP",                                                                                                                                                                                          
  "out_timestamp": "2018-02-23 09:09:00.0",                                                                                                                                                                
  "tail": "B-XXXX"},                                                                                                                                                                                       
 {"airline": "JYX",                                                                                                                                                                                        
  "arrivaltime": "2018-02-23 23:57:00.0",                                                                                                                                                                  
  "departuretime": "2018-02-23 20:42:00.0",                                                                                                                                                                
  "flightno": "XX1022",                                                                                                                                                                                    
  "fltdate": "2018-02-23",                                                                                                                                                                                 
  "fltdest": "ZSWZ",                                                                                                                                                                                       
  "fltdest_iata": "",                                                                                                                                                                                      
  "fltid": "1036068",                                                                                                                                                                                      
  "fltori": "ZYHB",                                                                                                                                                                                        
  "fltori_iata": "",                                                                                                                                                                                       
  "in_timestamp": "",                                                                                                                                                                                      
  "msid": "ONRP",                                                                                                                                                                                          
  "out_timestamp": "2018-02-23 20:37:00.0",                                                                                                                                                                
  "tail": "B-YYYY"}]                                                                                                                                                                                       
"""                                                                                                                                                                                                        

b = json.loads(a)                                                                                                                                                                                          
print "A:"                                                                                                                                                                                                 
pprint.pprint(a)                                                                                                                                                                                           
print "B:"                                                                                                                                                                                                 
pprint.pprint(b)
```

This is why the JSON module exists.

If your data is really structured like this, try using `literal_eval` from the `ast` module. It will evaluate python code as data in a safe(ish) way.